# Using reduce function for json response

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "totalPages": 13
    },
    "data": [{
        "type": "articles",
        "id": "3",
        "attributes": {
            "title": "AAAAA",
            "body": "BBBB",
            "created": "2011-06-22T14:56:29.00z",
            "updated": "2011-06-22T14:56:28.00z"
        }
    }],
    "links": {
        "self": "http://example.com/articles?page[number]=3&page[size]=1",
        "first": "http://example.com/articles?page[number]=1&page[size]=1",
        "prev": "http://example.com/articles?page[number]=2&page[size]=1",
        "next": "http://example.com/articles?page[number]=4&page[size]=1",
        "last": "http://example.com/articles?page[number]=1&page[size]=1"
    }
}
```

Suppose I'm getting this Json as response from a web server, is there a way somehow to use [reduce()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp) method here?

I tried like:

```
$.ajax({
  url:"http://...",
  type: "GET",
  headers:{"application/vnd+json"},
  success: function(data){
  var r = data.cells.reduce(function(array, object) {
    return array.concat(object.type);
   }, {});

  console.log(r);
 }
)};
```

Is it possible at all to use reduce here? My task is to use reduce function for the given Json. Is my AJAX ok?

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're asking about the use of `reduce()` but haven't explained *why* you want to use it. Rather than asking about your solution, consider asking about the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Agreed with @TylerRoper. What is your end goal? What are you trying to achieve with this JSON ?

Comment: My task is only to use `reduce()` function, I just need a simple usage to that given Json, you can choose the *why*

Comment: "My task is only to use reduce() function", Then try this: `success: () => [].reduce(() => 0)`

Comment: Ok, try `success: () => [].reduce(() => 1+1)`. If you need more "logic", just add more numbers. Maybe even use multiplication for extra "logic".

Comment: I'm trying to point out by examples what @TylerRoper said. There's a reason why every single comment here is asking you to clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: I said very clearly what I need, to use reduce function on this **Json** @junvar

Comment: @Devy Simply put, this question is off-topic for StackOverflow. Asking for "any use of `reduce()`" can't possibly have any answer that's more correct than any other. It is not nearly specific enough and is covered entirely by [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). It isn't clear why junvar's suggestion isn't sufficient; without an actual desired outcome, why do you need "logic"? How much "logic" is enough "logic"? What even constitutes more or less "logic"?

Comment: @Devy Because quite frankly this is a bad question, and answering bad questions encourages them. It's not likely you're going to get answers because answering off-topic questions is strongly discouraged. If we answer the question, we are likely to be *downvoted*. We're trying to help you, but first you need to help *us*. "With all these comments you could write 5 answers" - Similarly, with all of your comments, you could surely have clarified your question.

Comment: I can't see how a good answer could be written for this. There's no *practical problem* to be solved. It sounds like you just have a homework task of "demonstrate you know how to use `reduce()`", in which case you should go and read the documentation. MDN is a good source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you can use `reduce()` to calculate the count of data objects where `type:"articles"`

```
const response = {
    "meta": {
        "totalPages": 13
    },
    "data": [{
        "type": "articles",
        "id": "3",
        "attributes": {
            "title": "AAAAA",
            "body": "BBBB",
            "created": "2011-06-22T14:56:29.00z",
            "updated": "2011-06-22T14:56:28.00z"
        }
    },{
        "type": "articles",
        "id": "6",
        "attributes": {
            "title": "AAAAA",
            "body": "BBBB",
            "created": "2011-06-22T14:56:29.00z",
            "updated": "2011-06-22T14:56:28.00z"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "articles",
        "id": "10",
        "attributes": {
            "title": "AAAAA",
            "body": "BBBB",
            "created": "2011-06-22T14:56:29.00z",
            "updated": "2011-06-22T14:56:28.00z"
        }
    }],
    "links": {
        "self": "http://example.com/articles?page[number]=3&page[size]=1",
        "first": "http://example.com/articles?page[number]=1&page[size]=1",
        "prev": "http://example.com/articles?page[number]=2&page[size]=1",
        "next": "http://example.com/articles?page[number]=4&page[size]=1",
        "last": "http://example.com/articles?page[number]=1&page[size]=1"
    }
}

const totalArticles = response.data.reduce((count, val)=>{
  if(val.type === 'articles') count++
  return count;
  }, 0)

console.log(`Total no. of articles : ${totalArticles}`); // Total no. of articles : 3
```